# Query IBM domino server linux package

Tags: linux, rpm, ibm, ibm-domino

I have used `rpm -qa` to export the list of package installed on the linux machine. After which, I didn't see any IBM domino server related packages in the exported file.

May I know what is the possible situations that prevents IBM domino server related packages from exporting into the file. And what are the possible methods for me to find out whether domino server is installed in the machine?

Answer (score 0):

This was a long time ago but, last time, I remember that domino was installed from a CD and it was not using rpm packages.

Please give more details about the first question.

For the second question:

You can find if domino is installed by searching for directory/files specific to lotus domino:
/local/notesdata, /opt/lotus and for default linux user "notes".

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your information - i didn't know that domino was installed from CD last time! I'm not sure how the domino server is being installed but I am tasked to find out any server running domino server. Thats when I thought of using rpm to export the installed package and from there detect any domino package. This leads to my first question - what kind of scenarios that lead to no domino rpm package but domino services is running.

Comment: you should make the 'non answer' bits of this into comments on the question.